# node/mssql/async attempting to execute unknown number of queries serially

Tags: sql-server, node.js, asynchronous, transactions

I am using node.js v10.4.1 with packages mssql and async. I am attempting to execute multiple queries in serial with promises, however, there comes a point where I need to execute a set of queries the exact number of which is unknown until run time. I was trying to use async.mapSeries for that. Please see code below. Note the queries are wrapped in a transaction because either all the inserts must succeed or all must fail (i.e. be rolled back).

```
const theTransaction = thePool.transaction();
theTransaction.begin(err => {
    if (err) {
        //handle err here
    };
    console.log("Begin write issue transaction...");
    theTransaction.request()
        .input("myInputParameter", sql.NVarChar, myInputParameter)
        .query("insert into ... values ...")
        .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    var theList = getInsertedList(); // returns array of string 
                    async.mapSeries(theList, async (item, next) => {
                       console.log(item);
                       theTransaction.request()
                          .input("parameter", sql.NVarChar, item)
                          .query("insert into ... values ...")
                          .then(next);
                    });
             }) // error handling left out for brevity
       .then(result => {
                   console.log("Committing...");
                   theTransaction.commit(); // error handling left out
                   console.log("Committed.");
             })
       .catch(err => {
                   console.log("Aborting...");
                   theTransaction.rollback(); // error handling left out
                   console.log("Transaction rolled back.");
             });
    });
```

(It is possible I made a syntax error in porting my code into this comment, but my original code compiles and loads fine.)

On running this, I get the error:

```
RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state
```

which I interpret to mean subsequent queries in the mapSeries are not waiting for previous queries to finish. The error happens after the first query from the mapSeries list.

Any thoughts on how to fix this would be appreciated.

I was thinking I might have to build a single query syntactically as a string from theList and just execute one query in the .then. The problem with this approach is that in that case I need to include the parameters in the query string directly as opposed to using .input (which is not ideal as it opens the possibility for SQL injection attacks).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the queries as map. Then it will not depend on then number of query that you pass.

```
const request = new sql.Request();
for (key in inputMap) {
  request.input(key, inputMap[key]);
}
```